# Looping through xml elements starting with a certain element

Tags: c#, xml

How can I loop through a node's elements but from a specific element innertext?

For example:

```xml
<Available>
    <Item>
        <Value>120</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value>121</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Value>122</Value>
    </Item>
</Available>
```

The loop looks like this :

```
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("Available/Item"))
{
    //code
}
```

How can I start the loop from a certain element?
For example , I want it to loop through the elements starting with the "item" which has the value 121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("Available/Item").SkipWhile(n => n.Value != 121))
{
    //code
}
```